# Accessing a property in an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

Simple question that I am struggling to find answer for. I have an array as follows:

```
$t = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
print_r($t);
```

and the result is:

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
       (
           [term_id] => 4
           [name] => tag2
           [slug] => tag2
           [term_group] => 0
           [term_taxonomy_id] => 4
           [taxonomy] => post_tag
           [description] => 
           [parent] => 0
           [count] => 7
       )

   [1] => stdClass Object
       (
           [term_id] => 7
           [name] => tag5
           [slug] => tag5
           [term_group] => 0
           [term_taxonomy_id] => 7
           [taxonomy] => post_tag
           [description] => 
           [parent] => 0
           [count] => 6
       )

   [2] => stdClass Object
       (
           [term_id] => 16
           [name] => tag6
           [slug] => tag6
           [term_group] => 0
           [term_taxonomy_id] => 16
           [taxonomy] => post_tag
           [description] => 
           [parent] => 0
           [count] => 2
       )

)
```

how do I get the value of [COUNT] value in the array of the first [0], second[1] and third[2]?

Comment: `$t[0]->count`, `$t[1]->count`, `$t[2]->count`

Comment: thanks .. I've been looking for a solution up to 1 hour. and finally resolved by you.

Comment: Would anybody agree that the title is confusing? I don't know if I should change it to: `Accessing a property in an array of objects`, or would that one be too radical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<?php

foreach ($t as $val) {
    echo $val->count;
}

?>
```